# Existe um "else while"?

Tags: javascript, loop, else

Existe algum modo de eu fazer isso? Enquanto for uma coisa fazer isso, aí quando for outra fazer aquilo?

Por exemplo:

```
var i = 0; 
while(i < 5){
   //faça isso
   i++;
} else {
   //faça aquilo
}
```

É possível fazer isso de algum jeito?

Comment: Não tem `else` para uma laço de repetição.

Comment: pode explicar melhor o que aconteceria dentro do bloco `else`? Porque pra mim se você remover o `else` já resolve.

Comment: @mercador, editei!

Comment: Não é mais simples só inverter a condição? `if(..... > 1){ executa a função }` Não sei qual é a finalidade do while nesse código.

Comment: Como dito pelo rray Não existe `else` para laços de repetição e provavelmente você não precise dele. Acredito que um simples `If`  deva solucionar seu problema, o que precisamos entender melhor é como você cria o elemento `#recomendation-sizebay-span` para saber aonde colocar o `if` ou a chamada da função `arrumaSzb()`.

Comment: Então, esse é o problema, esse #recomendation-sizebay-span vem pelo GTM do Google, e ele é sempre o ultimo elemento carregado na página. Se eu usar IF, sempre o length vai dar 0, então não adianta executar a função se o #recomendation-sizebay-span ainda não existe.

Comment: Google Tag Manager

Comment: Se for uma função do google ou script deve existir algum tipo de call back, Cita o uso do GTM na sua pergunta e inclui o código. Um bom começo é  dar uma olhada na documentação do google a fim de verificar se já existe algo implementado.

Comment: Não me parece um problema exclusivo do GTM a ponto de precisar de tag ou menção. Creio que a pergunta se aplica a qualquer contexto de programação.

Comment: Não quis dizer adicionar uma tag, mas acho interessante existir na pergunta o código que cria o elemento que deve ser "observado", existe outras formas como verificar constantemente a existência dele mas não acho que seja a melhor solução.

Comment: Reverti sua questão pois altera completamente o sentido original e invalida a resposta já dada e votada. Se tem uma dúvida diferente, faça em pergunta separada.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Em JS não existe, precisa criar uma *flag* dentro do laço para um `if` ser executado ou não após o fim deste laço. Ou pensar em um fluxo diferente que não precise disto.

[Em Python existe](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement).

O exemplo da pergunta não é bom porque ele não precisa deste algoritmo. Na verdade isto pode ser resolvido com um `for` simples. Se o dado da condição fosse desconhecido poderia fazer algo assim:

```js
var entrada = 1; //teria que ser uma valor desconhecido
var entrou = false;
while (entrada < 10) {
    entrou = true;
    //faz algo mais aqui, caso contrário não teria sentido
    entrada++;
}
if (!entrou) {
    console.log("deu problema");
}
console.log("vamos tentar de novo");
var entrada = 11; //teria que ser uma valor desconhecido
var entrou = false;
while (entrada < 10) {
    entrou = true;
    //faz algo mais aqui, caso contrário não teria sentido
    entrada++;
}
if (!entrou) {
    console.log("deu problema");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/ElseWhile.js).

Cuidado com as soluções que usam a própria condição para decidir se vai executar ou não, ou se usa uma condição invertida depois do laço. Isto tende a gerar *bugs* com a manutenção. Isto viola o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Até mesmo de início pode gerar um *bug*  e não perceber.

Dependendo da condição pode chamar uma função que tem efeito colateral ou provocar uma condição de corrida e produzir um resultado inesperado. É provável que você teste e funcione. Mas um dia acontece algo que não funciona já que não está certo. Funcionar e estar certo são coisas distintas.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Answer (score -2):

Da forma como escreveu o código não existe **else** em javascript.

Sugiro reescrever seu código de outra maneira, por exemplo:

```
 while(i < 5){
   //faça alguma coisa
 }

 if(i >= 5){
   //faça outra couisa
 }
```

Não sei se essa é a ação que deva ser tomada. Caso não seja nos explique melhor o que pretende que o código faça.

Comment: Dá uma lida na minha para entender o problema que isto pode trazer.

Comment: É só colocar o `i++` dentro do `while` que você verá o problema.

Comment: É verdade. Esse é uma situação atípica, pelo menos pra mim. Não me recordo de uma situação onde precisei de um `while {} ... else`.